# Wordpress dropdown not working in my theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I can't seem to know what I'm doing wrong. The dropdown navigation appears when I'm using the default wordpres twentyeleven theme but when I swith to my theme, the dropdown doesn't appear. This is what I'm using

```
<div id="nav" class="menutwo">

    <ul id="myStyle">
        <?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&depth=1&title_li=');?>
    </ul>

<br style="clear: left" />
</div>
```

I made 3 pages (boo, boo1, boo2) at the wordpress back office and made them children of (foo), yet only foo is appearing but the children (boo, boo1, boo2) are not appearing. I looked it up in the wordpress codex but my problem was not solved :(. Why is the problem from? I've jquery included btw :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might be buggy php script. use this:-

```
<ul id="myStyle">
 <? wp_list_pages('title_li=&sort_column=menu_order'); ?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome, inspect any element, and then go to sources and see if you linked your jquery file correctly.  If so, all of the code will appear, and if not, nothing will appear when you attempt to read the file from the server.

I like to use this bit of code to call up the correct url to each link to files in my header.php

`<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>`

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

Also, what is the url to your site?

Comment: all javascript on the page are working. My problem is the child page fails to appear under the parent page in a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need css fixes.
Here is a very good [article](http://techsloution4u.com/wordpress/create-a-css3-dropdown-menu-in-wordpress.html) for making drop-down menu in WordPress.
Hope this will help
Thanks